# Starting DB connections before load Express 4.x

Tags: database, node.js, asynchronous, express

I might be missing something but there doesn't seem to be anything in the official documentation, so I'm stuck asking here;

I'm trying to set up some stuff asynchronously (connections to databases, etc) when the application starts. I want this to complete before the app becomes ready to accept connections (for obvious reasons).

Is there a way to do this in Express 4.x?

Here is [an example](https://github.com/tj/express-configuration) of basically what I want, however it's unsupported and 4 years out of date at this point.

Any help is appreciated.

**Edit:** I feel I should point out that I used `express-generator` to setup my application, so all the server listening is done inside `bin/www`. Should I just modify this file? Or can I control it from `app.js`?

Comment: What database you use?

Comment: @user3776269 this doesn't really matter, because it's just the concept I'm interested in :) but you can assume mongodb, as it's a good example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example you can use promises, something like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();

var Q = require('q');
var d = Q

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/db', function(){
    return d.resolve();
});

d.promise.then(function(){
    app.listen(8080);
});
```

Comment: That's kinda the thing though; Express 4.0 gave me `bin/www` to start up my app, and I no longer manually call `app.listen`. Or are you suggesting to just modify that file?